# How do you create a custom OSObject subclass in a DriverKit driver?

Tags: c++, ios, macos, iokit, driverkit

In my DriverKit driver, I'd like to create a custom class that inherits from `OSObject` so that I can store it in an `OSArray` (and other `OSObject` derived collections).

The documentation for kexts and IOKit indicates that you use the `OSDeclareDefaultStructors` and `OSDefineMetaClassAndStructors` macros to define constructors, destructors, and the metaclass info. However, these macros don't seem to exist in DriverKit.

I've done something like this:

```cpp
class MyCustomObject: public OSObject
{
    using super = OSObject;

public:
    virtual bool init() override;
    virtual void free() override;
}

bool MyCustomClass::init()
{
    if (!super::init()) {
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "[Driver] MyCustomClass super::init() failed");
        return false;
    }
    
    // Initialize stuff

    return true;
}

void MyCustomClass::free(void)
{
    // Release retained members

    super::free();
}
```

That works as far as it goes, and compiles. But I can't `new` an instance of it, which also means I don't know how to implement the traditional static `withFoo()` type method to create one.

Is creating a custom `OSObject` subclass in a DriverKit dext supported? If so, how should that be set up?

Answer (score 0):

It should work via the [`OSTypeAlloc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ostypealloc) macro. You'll still need to call `init()`, and may want to implement a `static` factory method wrapping both, similar to how other DriverKit classes do it.

If you're still having trouble, try defining the class in an `.iig`. I forget if that's required. (I think probably not, as your class won't be bridged between DriverKit and the kernel.)

Comment: Thanks, @pmdj. OSTypeAlloc expects there to be a `gMyCustomObjectMetaClass`. I see that other Driver/IOKit classes declare that kind of thing in their headers, but it's not completely clear what it should be initialized with. I am already defining the class in an `.iig`, for whatever that's worth.